# Length of Multi dimension array in bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I have a 2D Array in bash script,I want to know the length of each dimension .

```
for example :
array[1,1] = 1    array[1,2] = 1
array[2,1] = 1    array[2,2] = 1
array[3,1] = 1    array[3,2] = 1
array[4,1] = 1    array[4,2] = 1
the number of rows : 4
```

the main script :

all comments are appreciated

Comment: Can you show what you mean by 2D array?

Comment: something like this matrix[$length,1]=value

Comment: `matrix[$length,1]=value` assigns to `matrix[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Bash doesn't support multidimensional arrays. The list in square brackets is evaluated along the C rules for the comma operator, i.e. it returns the last element:

```
matrix[0,1]=a
echo ${matrix[0]}   # nothing
echo ${matrix[1]}   # a
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a numerically indexed array, @choroba is totally right: 
the contents of the square brackets is evaluated arithmetically.

```
$ for i in $(seq 5); do for j in $(seq 6); do arr[$i,$j]="$i$j"; done; done
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([1]="51" [2]="52" [3]="53" [4]="54" [5]="55" [6]="56")'
```

If you use an associative array, you can fake multidimensionality:

```
$ unset arr; declare -A arr
$ for i in $(seq 5); do for j in $(seq 6); do arr[$i,$j]="$i$j"; done; done
$ declare -p arr
```

> `declare -A arr='([5,1]="51" [3,6]="36" [5,3]="53" [3,5]="35" [5,2]="52" [3,4]="34" [5,5]="55" [3,3]="33" [5,4]="54" [3,2]="32" [3,1]="31" [5,6]="56" [2,6]="26" [2,4]="24" [2,5]="25" [2,2]="22" [2,3]="23" [2,1]="21" [4,1]="41" [4,2]="42" [4,3]="43" [4,4]="44" [4,5]="45" [4,6]="46" [1,5]="15" [1,4]="14" [1,6]="16" [1,1]="11" [1,3]="13" [1,2]="12" )'`

But it's still a one-dimensional array

```
$ echo "${#arr[@]}"
30
```

You have to know some of the contents of the array to find the dimensions (assuming it's a square "matrix")

```
$ i=1; printf "%s\n" "${!arr[@]}" | grep "^$i,"
1,5
1,4
1,6
1,1
1,3
1,2
$ j=1; printf "%s\n" "${!arr[@]}" | grep ",$j$"
5,1
3,1
2,1
4,1
1,1
```

Comment: actually I don't know the length of Array (the array is built by a loop) . I want to know how to create such an array in a loop , and how to count its rows, assume the array has two dimension the first one is fixed (columns) the second one will change during run time .

Comment: echo "${#arr[@]}" --> this command worked for me , but how to assign it to a variable ....    lenght=${#matrix[@]}
                        echo "${lengthl}"

Comment: actually I want to know the row number

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Please add more detail to your question.